# PowerApps SharePoint Online - call JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, azure, sharepoint, powerapps

I have a custom form for a new item in SharePoint list. I added a javascript code (JSOM) to create a folder and SPGroup with the info given in the form. This is working in classic view, but when I change to the 'new experience' view a PowerApp form is shown to enter new item. So, how I can do the same functionality for SharePoint online using PowerApps? do I have to use Azure functions? or would be better to create a SharePoint Add-ins?. I was reading some info and looks like PowerApps does not allow to add a link to the js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some days of research and testing I ended up with some useful links to create functions on Azure with CSOM and call them from Flow using HTTP Actions. I think this is the way how to create workflows in SharePoint Online, since Flow has limited actions to work with SharePoint Groups, permissions, Libraries.

[azure-functions-csom](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-azure-functions-from-sharepoint-components/)

[azure-function-flow](https://veenstra.me.uk/2017/08/02/azure-function-apps-sharepoint-lists-creating-web-hooks-that-run-powershell-triggered-by-item-creation/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a custom API for your Azure function and use that API directly in powerapps (through adding a data source). Azure provides features to generate swagger definition and exporting the generated file to powerapps/flow.